# HTML table in pandas with single header row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
 ID     mutex add  atomic add  cas add  ys_add  blocking ticket  queued fifo
Cores                                                                      
1           21.0         7.1     12.1     9.8             32.2         44.6
2          121.8        40.0    119.2   928.7           7329.9       7460.1
3          160.5        81.5    227.9  1640.9          14371.8      11802.1
4          188.9       115.7    347.6  1945.1          29130.5      15660.1
```

There is both a column index (`ID`) and a row index (`Cores`). When I use `DataFrame.to_html()`, I get a table like this:

[image: Actual]

Instead, I'd like a table with a single header row, composed of all the column names (but without the column index name `ID`) and with the row index name `Cores` in that same header row, like so:

[image: Desired]

I'm open to manipulating the dataframe prior to the `to_html()` call, or adding parameters to the `to_html()` call, but not messing around with the generated `html`.

Comment: You could use `df.drop([0], axis=0)`and then  use `df.rename{ 'ID' : 'Cores'}`

Comment: `df.rename_axis(columns=None )`

Comment: @QuangHoang - I had already tried this. It doesn't change the output except that `ID` disapears: the `Cores` cell still appears in a separate header row from all the column header, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It6V0.png).

Comment: did you reassign, i.e. `df = df.rename_axis(columns=None)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, yes, I did. This simply removes the index name, but `Cores` and the list of column names are still different things entire and even the dataframe text output reflects (it still has cores on a different line from the column headers).

Comment: `df.rename_axis(index=None, columns='Cores').to_html()` would do.

Comment: How about this: `df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index().to_html(index=False)`

Comment: @AnuragReddy - `subf.drop([0], axis=0)` doesn't work because there is no row with label `0` (the labels are 1 through 4). Maybe you wanted `index=[0]`? This will note remove `Cores` but rather drop the first row (label 1).

Comment: @QuangHoang - that version works great! I used `df.rename_axis(index=None, columns=df.index.name)` in order not to hardcode `Cores`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initial setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]],
                 columns = ['attr_a', 'attr_b', 'attr_c', 'attr_c'])

df.columns.name = 'ID'
df.index.name = 'Cores'
df

ID  attr_a  attr_b  attr_c  attr_c
Cores               
0        1       2       3       4
1        5       6       7       8
2        9      10      11      12
3       13      14      15      16
```

Then set columns.name to 'Cores', and index.name to None.  df.to_html() should then give you the output you want.

```
df.columns.name='Cores'
df.index.name = None
df.to_html()


Cores   attr_a  attr_b  attr_c  attr_c
0            1       2       3       4
1            5       6       7       8
2            9      10      11      12
3           13      14      15      16
```